# How to get token address inside a crowdsale contract, if you create separate migration files?

Tags: truffle, erc-20, truffle-migration, crowdsale

To expand on the question, I have created an erc20 token contract, & a crowdsale contract. For each file, I intend to create separate migration files.

How can i get the token address for reference in the crowdsale contract?

Thank you

---

Sidenote:
I am aware of the general approach, most contracts have a single migration file, say deploy.js. In which, crowdsale contract inherits the token address through a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Truffle has functionality `deployed()` which, if I remember right, gets the contract deployed during migrations. Documentation on that is a bit flimsy: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts

So you can get the instance with `deployed()` and use its address in the next migration file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by using a `.env` file on my root directory.

I used the npm package [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to fetch the variables. They are available throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it worked out.

In the crowdsale migration.js, I've deployed token contract first, fetched the address through async. Assigned it to a const. This const thereafter acted as a pointer to the token contract.

**Migration code below**

```
const Crowdsale = artifacts.require("contracts/Crowdsale.sol");
const Token = artifacts.require("contracts/Token.sol");

module.exports = async function(deployer, network, accounts)  {
  
  const deployedNetwork = await Token.deployed();
  const _rate = 100;
  const _tokenAvailable = 1000;
  
  const _token = deployedNetwork.address;
  const _wallet = accounts[6];
  

  return deployer.deploy(Crowdsale, _rate, _wallet, _token, _tokenAvailable); 

};
```